# AutoRun script runs twice

Tags: windows-7, windows, conemu

The HelpDesk guys decided that they had to re-image my laptop this week. Now I'm trying to set all of my development tools back up.  I'm running Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.

I have a script (**cmd-profile.bat**) that sets up a bunch of macros and aliases and then echos "Chris's command macros loaded".  I added it to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.  When I run cmd.com, I see this:

```
Chris's command macros loaded.

C:\Users\christopher.nash>
```

Then I installed ConEmu.  When it loads, I see this:

```
Chris's command macros loaded.                       
C:\Users\christopher.nash>ECHO OFF                   
♀Chris's command macros loaded.                      
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]                 

christopher.nash@CNASH-W530 C:\Users\christopher.nash
$
```

Why does it run my **cmd-profile.bat** twice?

Comment: Can you provide the actual code that's in the batch file?

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take fresh [CmdInit.cmd from Preview branch](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/preview/Release/ConEmu/CmdInit.cmd).

Execution of `ver` had triggered double execution of your batch.